# Как отправить HTTP запросы на адрес сервера методом POST на URL через PHP?

Tags: php

Как отправить `HTTP` запросы на адрес сервера методом `POST` на `URL` через `PHP`? (Возвращает `JSON`)

Comment: [php отправить HTTP запрос методом POST](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aru.stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions+php+отправить+HTTP+запрос+методом+POST) - **три тысячи** ответов

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант:

```
$url = 'http://your_site/POST.php';

$params = array(
    'param1' => 'data',
    'param2' => 'data',
);

$result = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => http_build_query($params)
    )
)));

echo $result;
```

Comment: Если вам нужна более тонкая настройка - можете использовать `curl`